# How to handle multiple 0Auth Access tokens

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I'm developing a system to get buyers data from a sales website and send it to the business' CRM as a contact, all through REST API using 0Auth 2.0 on both sides. So far so good, but the thing is multiple businesses could be using the server at the same time, so I would need to handle multiple access tokens.

I thought of maybe storing the access tokens, with the user id and the refresh tokens on an external database but I don't know how secure and efficient that would be, since it would need to query the user id every time it needs to get access to either API.

Is there a way to actually handle this in a more elegant way?

Comment: Is the system you are writing is some kind of a scheduled job server?

Comment: It's basically an API gateway where I take data from a server and parse it to other, all through REST, but I need the auth from both sides in order to exchange info.